# Setting registers in hardware peripherals

Tags: c, pointers, cpu-registers

Right now I'm reading a beginner-level book called 'Programming Embedded Systems'.  It has one section explaining how to manipulate registers on a peripheral device using C.

It has an example at the beginning I just don't get.

```
uint32_t *pGpio0Set = (uint32_t *)(0x40E00018);
```

I think this is declaring a pointer to a 32-bit unsigned integer.  What I can also guess is that the register in question controls a GPIO and that the register lives at address 0x40E00018.

What I don't understand is what the (uint32_t *) preceding (0x40E00018) means and what effect it has.

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a [**type cast**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#C-like_languages). It generally converts a type to another. In this case it converts a hex number to an address. The parentheses around that hex number are superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cast from integer type to a pointer to integer.
If you would not do that, the compiler will complaint that you assign an integer to a different type. Even a pointer **is** mostly simply a an integer (what is not true at any platform), the compiler want to be sure, that you really intend to use the number as address.